# How to Create sticky session in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

My Configurations are:-

`frontend http-8081
    bind *:8081
    mode http
    acl is_keycloak hdr(X-TARGET) keycloak
    use_backend keycloak if is_keycloak`

`backend keycloak
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server 192.168.99.100:32768 192.168.99.101:32766 check inter 5000`

I am new to this and I need a Sticky session. Can anyone tell me using this configuration that how to create a Sticky session?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using cookies will help you here.
I would also say have your servers on seperate lines for each one

```
cookie SERVERID insert
server s1 192.168.99.100:32768 check inter 5000 check cookie s1
server s2 192.168.99.101:32766 check inter 5000 check cookie s2
```